# Google Charts - Table has no columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am stuck with Google Charts.
The linegraph displays two values: `Temperature` and `Humidity`.

Since I added ajax to my chart, it doesn't load anymore and I get the Message:

> Table has no columns.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($table); ?>;
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  setInterval(drawChart, 10000);
  function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getTemp.php',
      type: 'get',
      success: function (json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        var options = {
          title: 'Raspberry:',
          curveType: 'function',
          'height':400
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

Edit: This is my php-file: getTemp.php , if you need anything else let me know.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Device_Data');
    $rows = array();
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
                         array('label' => 'Timestamp', 'type' => 'string'),
                         array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number'),
                         array('label' =>  'Humidity', 'type' => 'number')
                     );
    foreach($result as $r) {
        $data = array();
        $data[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Timestamp']);
        $data[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Temperature']);
        $data[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Humidity']);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $data);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $result2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT 'Temperature','Humidity', 'Timestamp' from Device_Data;");      
    $result2->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Where is this code block in relation to everything else?  Is $table declared ahead of time, or after this code block?  If the <?php variable hasn't been created yet, please delete this question and fix up your order of things.

Comment: i added my php-file, getTemp.php

Comment: what is `json` output?

Comment: I have no idea, i only display the data in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit / Second Attempt:

I think the variable is out of scope.

Please apply `<?php echo json_encode($table); ?>` directly.

So that it looks like:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($table); ?>);
```

Then you can remove the old `var jsonData ...` part, and delete all instances of `json` in the success function.